# Create SuperUser in postgresql Windows

Tags: windows, postgresql, connection, phppgadmin

I'm trying to create a new user and set up a password for it in postgresql in Windowns 7.

I tried: 
1. Start menu > All Programs > PostgreSQL 9.5 > psql to 'postgres'
2. Type in: CREATE ROLE username LOGIN PASSWORD 'password

However, when I try to login with that user and password through http://127.0.0.1/phppgadmin/  I cannot log in.

Also, what is the default password for the postgres user? I haven't been to log in at all.

Do I need to have Apache to be running to be able to connect? If so, how do I run it?

Thank you so much

Comment: Do you really use PostgreSQL 8.3 ?! You really should upgrade your database

Comment: Sorry a mistake typing. I use 9.5

Comment: Hi Looking at the The pg_hba.conf File might help you Ref [http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html]

Comment: The default password is what every you set the postgres user in the operating system / windows